# iPhone:How to give URL link to the Text?

Tags: iphone

I have Text(http://www.mywebsite.com) in a view, in which i need to provide URL link, so that clicking on that one will take user to the browser.

How do i achieve it? Please provide your suggestions.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your text as a UIButton add the following code to the touch-up-inside action:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com/"]];
```

Comment: Thanks. I should keep url text in my application About screen, which does also has some other text too. So i don't think WebView is not good to add in About screen. 
As Kevin said, if we can keep this under a button, how can we have button without rectangle shape(so that it doesn't look like button) and show us text with underlined?

Comment: Hi. In interface builder, select your button and hit [command][shift][i] then change the type to 'custom' to remove the rectangle outline. As for the underline, I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I don't know who has made down vote for your answer. I'll make that correct.

Comment: No worries, just thought it might not have worked, so I made a project and tested. Seems OK to me.

Answer (score 1):

Display the text using [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)